# Mongoose multiple requests to build another without nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've got an app in which I'm taking a POST request with 2 variables.
Next I take info from three collections based on those variables.
And with collected data i make save request to another collection.
What I've got now is weird structure like

```
One.findOne({var: variable}, function(err, one) {
    Two.findOne({var: variable}, function(err, two) {
        Three.findOne({var: two.something}, function(err, three) {
            var something = new Four();
            something.data = {one: one, two: two, three: three};
            something.Save();
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any possibility to make it like the one below?
Or is it proper to build that nested build?
Or maybe I should rethink my db structure?

```
 GetOne();
 GetTwo();
 GetThree();
 var something = new Four();
 var something = new Four();
 something.data = {one: one, two: two, three: three};
 something.Save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I rearranged my question to google and found a solution:
https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel
async.